# which python version supports rpi gpio libraries?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-3b+

im working on raspberry pi 3 b +model i installed noobs on it ,but when i try to install rpi gpio libraries it shows their is no module named rpi gpio it is showing ,and when i want to see which version of python is on my rasp, so i typed sudo python then i got python 2.7.3.0 it is showing but wen i go to raspberry windows programming section it is showing python 3(IDLE) .please help me out how to install those rpi and gpio libraries on my pi 3 model.Iam worried about my project .

Comment: On Raspban Desktop RPi.GPIO is installed for Python 2 and 3. `it shows their is no module named rpi gpio` Did you get the capitlisation right? It's `RPi.GPIO` , not `rpi.gpio`.

Comment: hello tq for your kind reply .....ya the capitalisation is correct ...their it is showing err 1 archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf python3ßrpi.gpioßd bgsym armhf 0.6.3 stretch 1

Comment: temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'

Comment: this is what iam getting on my terminal ..please help me regarding this issue

Comment: I'm not talking capitalisation for installing RPi.GPIO, but using it in a Python script. Did you get capitalisation correct in the Python script? Please add your code and any error messages to the question. They are unintelligible in these comments.

Comment: And please edit your question to make it easier to read (capitalisation, punctuation and use of paragraphs)

Comment: hello sir below is the code

Comment: import RPi.GPIO as IO            # calling header file for GPIO’s of PI
 import time                              # calling for time to provide delays in programm

Comment: Please read my previous comments about updating your question instead of adding code, etc to comments

Comment: hello sir,sorry for your inconvinience ...when i try to run import RPi.GPIO as IO ,its is sowing the import error as no module named RPI .so i have installed noobs on my raspberry pi3 b + model and when i navigate to raspberry pi3 b+ desktop programming section ,  python 3(idle) is installed ,but when i type python in terminal it is showing python 2.3.6.0 . Is internet required to update libraries?.

Comment: Use `python` to start Python 2, `python3`to run Python 3. You can also use 'idle' from the CLI to start IDLE 2. It's still there, its just the menu item that has been disabled (you can activate it again the menu editor). But you're mixing up 2 issues: which version of Python to start and whether RPIi.GPIO is installed. To make sure that RPi.GPIO is installed for Python 2 and 3 then run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio`

Comment: And again: please read my previous comments about updating your question instead of adding code, etc to comments

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here... and please be so kind to **EDIT** your question to include the details other users have been asking about. Please do not post those as comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both python 2 & 3 should be installed on your Pi if you have installed NOOBS. `sudo python` calls on python 2, `sudo python3` calls on python 3.

Also, if you have installed NOOBS, RPI GPIO should already be installed, you should be able to just import module in python script with no issue.

But, if for whatever reason it is not installed, `sudo apt-get install python-dev python-rpi.gpio` should install it.